# replace ascii code in string php

Tags: php, ascii

I have an app that stores survey responses. Some of the responses are plain-text responses with feedback.

When the person filling the survey out adds a line (his return on the key board) this creates a new paragraph.

It is stored in my `Postgres` database as an ascii character `chr(10)` (referring to it in Postgres terms).

This is all fine however the problem I am running into is when I display the values. My PDF printing app doesn't understand this ascii encoding and displays it all as one line. Instead of:

> One line
>   Two lines
>   Three lines

It returns it as:

> One line Two lines three lines

Makes for very long drawn out paragraphs...

I am trying to figure out how I can replace the ascii code with an html break `<br/>`.

I am obviously familiar with `str_replace` - the point is that I am not familiar with ascii at all and need some help on how to search for this in the string to replace with an HTML break `<br/>`.

Thank you.

Comment: That's probably a `\n` (or `\r\n`)

Comment: No, that didn't find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace line breaks with `<br />`, you can use the built-in PHP function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

e.g.

`$content = nl2br($content);`

(technically it inserts the BRs before the line breaks, so they're still there, but should work ok)

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect.